# Regex in Bash: not wanting to include directories

Tags: regex, bash, find

I have a list of images, collected using the following line:

```
# find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.JPG" | grep "MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG"
```

output:

```
./DCIM/103canon/IMG_0039.JPG
./DCIM/103canon/IMG_0097.JPG
./DCIM/103canon/IMG_1600.JPG
./DCIM/103canon/IMG_2317.JPG
./DCIM/IMG_0042.JPG
./DCIM/IMG_1152.JPG
./DCIM/IMG_1810.JPG
./DCIM/IMG_2564.JPG
./images/IMG_0058.JPG
./images/IMG_0079.JPG
./images/IMG_1233.JPG
./images/IMG_1959.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_0039.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_1060.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_1729.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_2013.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/favs/IMG_2317.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/IMG_0079.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/IMG_1403.JPG
./images/IMG_2012/IMG_2102.JPG
./images/IMG_2013/IMG_0060.JPG
./images/IMG_2013/IMG_1311.JPG
./images/IMG_2013/IMG_1729.JPG
./images/IMG_2013/IMG_2013.JPG
./IMG_0085.JPG
./IMG_1597.JPG
./IMG_2288.JPG
```

however I only want the very last portion, the IMG_\d\d\d\d.JPG. I have tried hundreds of regular expressions and this is the one that gives me the best result. Is there a way to only print out the filename without the directory tree before it or is is solely down to the regex?

Thanks

Comment: ah sorry, linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `-printf` option is not available with your implementation of `find` (as in current versions of Mac OS X),
then you can use `-execdir echo {} \;` instead (if that's available):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*MG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -execdir echo {} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't `-execdir` still prefix `./` to the basename?

Comment: @melpomene in my version of `find` it doesn't (Mac OS X)